# Spring AOP: Aspect class is not executed

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have defined an aspect which should be executed when the method getFirstName() is called on the User object. But it does not happen.

My Aspect class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class JpaGetFirstNameAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(* de.playground.model.User.getFirstName(..))")
  public void pointCutSetFirstName() {
  }

  @Before("pointCutGetFirstName()")
  public void beforeGetFirstName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(">>>> Before retrieving first name ... " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());  
  }

  @After("pointCutGetFirstName()")
  public void afterGetFirstName() {
    System.out.println(">>>> After execution of getFirstName method ... ");
  }

  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "pointCutGetFirstName()", returning = "firstName")
  public void afterReturningGetFirstName(JoinPoint joinPoint, String firstName) {
    System.out.println("<<<< " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("<<<< returned first name of user " + firstName);
  }

 @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "pointCutGetFirstName()", throwing = "exc")
  public void afterThrowingGetFirstName(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("|||| Retrieved Exception from getFirstName method ... " + exc.toString());
  }
}
```

My application-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       ">

  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:load-time-weaver />
  <context:component-scan base-package="de.playground.service" />

</beans>
```

My testclass:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml" })
public class AspectIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private GenericApplicationContext context;

  private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;

  public AspectIntegrationTest() {

  }


  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDownClass() {

  }

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass() {
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {

  }

  @Test
  public void testHijackingUser() {

    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    user1.setLastModified(new Date());
    user1.setFirstName("Max");
    user1.setLastName("Mustermann");
    user1.setUsername("max.mustermann");
    user1.setPassword("start123");
    System.out.println(">user 1 = " + user1.getFirstName());

    assertNotNull(user1);
  }
}
```

My aop.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
        <include within="de.playground.service.*"     />  
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- use only this aspect for weaving -->
        <aspect     name="de.playground.aspect.JpaGetFirstNameAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>de.playground.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>playground-dev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>playground-script</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${version.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <version.aspectj>1.8.5</version.aspectj>
    <version.spring>4.1.6.RELEASE</version.spring>
  </properties>
  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${version.spring}/spring-instrument-${version.spring}.jar"</argLine>
            <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: And it never will. Spring will only apply AOP on spring managed beans I highly doubt your `User` is a spring managed bean (nor should it be). If you want this you need full blown AspectJ with compile or load time weaving.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. My updated pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <forkMode>once</forkMode>
          <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${version.spring}/spring-instrument-${version.spring}.jar"</argLine>
          <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
          <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
          </aspectLibraries>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```